# How to handle self mutability during parallelization in Rust?

Tags: rust, parallel-processing, neural-network

I'm coding a Neural Network and I'm struggling with the training parallelization. I have two main structs:

**Model**

```
pub struct Model {
    layers: Vec<Layer>,
    loss: fn(&DMatrix<f32>, &DMatrix<f32>) -> f32,
    loss_derivative: fn(&DMatrix<f32>, &DMatrix<f32>) -> DMatrix<f32>,
}

impl Model {
    // Other not so relevant functions...

    pub fn fit(
        &mut self,
        batch_size: usize,
        epochs: usize,
        learning_rate: f32,
        metrics: Vec<String>,
        optimizer: &mut dyn Optimizer,
        x: Vec<DMatrix<f32>>,
        y: Vec<DMatrix<f32>>,
    ) {
        let mut x = x.clone();
        let mut y = y.clone();

        self.layers
            .iter_mut()
            .for_each(|layer| optimizer.initialize_layer_additional_params(layer));

        for epoch in 0..epochs {
            Self::shuffle_dataset(&mut x, &mut y);

            let batches = x.chunks(batch_size).zip(y.chunks(batch_size));

            let mut epoch_predictions = Vec::with_capacity(x.len());
            let mut epoch_loss = 0_f32;


            for (input_batch, target_batch) in batches {
                let mut batch_loss = 0_f32;

                for (input_data, target_data) in input_batch.iter().zip(target_batch.iter()) {
                    let mut prediction = self.evaluate(input_data);

                    batch_loss += (self.loss)(target_data, &prediction);

                    self.backpropagation(target_data, input_data, &prediction);

                    epoch_predictions.push(prediction);
                }

                self.layers.iter_mut().for_each(|layer| {
                    optimizer.update_params(input_batch.len(), layer, learning_rate);
                    layer.clear_error_and_delta()
                });

                epoch_loss += batch_loss as f32;
            }
            // Print metrics
        }
    }

    fn backpropagation(
        &mut self,
        expected: &DMatrix<f32>,
        network_input: &DMatrix<f32>,
        predicted: &DMatrix<f32>,
    ) { 
        // mutates self.layers storing the error for the sample
    }

    pub fn evaluate(&mut self, data: &DMatrix<f32>) -> DMatrix<f32> {
        let mut last_output = data;

        self.layers
            .iter_mut()
            .for_each(|layer| last_output = layer.forward(&last_output));

        last_output.clone()
    }
}
```

**Layer**

```
pub struct Layer {
    activation: fn(&DMatrix<f32>) -> DMatrix<f32>,
    activation_derivative: fn(&DMatrix<f32>) -> DMatrix<f32>,
    biases: DMatrix<f32>,
    deltas: DMatrix<f32>,
    errors: DMatrix<f32>,
    last_activated_output: DMatrix<f32>,
    last_raw_output: DMatrix<f32>,
    optimizer_params: HashMap<String, DMatrix<f32>>,
    weights: DMatrix<f32>,
}

impl Layer {
    // Other not so relevant functions

    pub fn forward(&mut self, data: &DMatrix<f32>) -> &DMatrix<f32> {
        self.last_raw_output = (&self.weights * data) + &self.biases;

        self.last_activated_output = (self.activation)(&self.last_raw_output);

        &self.last_activated_output
    }

    pub fn propagate_error(
        &self,
        last_layer: bool,
        next_layer_delta: &DMatrix<f32>,
        next_layer_weights: &DMatrix<f32>,
        previous_layer_output: &DMatrix<f32>,
    ) -> (DMatrix<f32>, DMatrix<f32>) {
        // https://sudeepraja.github.io/Neural/
        let activation_derivative = (self.activation_derivative)(&self.last_raw_output);

        let deltas = if last_layer {
            activation_derivative.component_mul(&next_layer_delta)
        } else {
            let next_layer_weighted_error = next_layer_weights.transpose() * next_layer_delta;

            next_layer_weighted_error.component_mul(&activation_derivative)
        };

        (&deltas * previous_layer_output.transpose(), deltas)
    }

    pub fn sum_errors_and_deltas(
        &mut self,
        deltas: &DMatrix<f32>,
        errors: &DMatrix<f32>,
    ) {
        self.errors += errors;
        self.deltas += deltas;
    }

    pub fn update_params(&mut self, learning_rate: f32, batch_size: usize) {
        let mut error = &self.errors / batch_size as f32;

        error.scale_mut(learning_rate);

        self.weights -= error;

        let mut deltas = &self.deltas / batch_size as f32;

        deltas.scale_mut(learning_rate);

        self.biases -= deltas;

        self.clear_error_and_delta()
    }

    pub fn clear_error_and_delta(&mut self) {
        self.deltas = DMatrix::zeros(self.weights.nrows(), 1);
        self.errors = DMatrix::zeros(self.weights.nrows(), self.weights.ncols());
    }
}
```

#### My goal

I'd like to parallelize this part inside the fit function in Model struct

```
for (input_batch, target_batch) in batches {
    let mut batch_loss = 0_f32;

    for (input_data, target_data) in input_batch.iter().zip(target_batch.iter()) {
        let mut prediction = self.evaluate(input_data);

        batch_loss += (self.loss)(target_data, &prediction);

        self.backpropagation(target_data, input_data, &prediction);

        epoch_predictions.push(prediction);
    }

    // This would be moved out the loop <---------------------
    self.layers.iter_mut().for_each(|layer| {
        optimizer.update_params(input_batch.len(), layer, learning_rate);
        layer.clear_error_and_delta()
    });

    epoch_loss += batch_loss as f32;
}
```

#### What I tried

I tried to use [Arc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) and [Mutex](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) but got myself not knowing how to handle `self` mutability, specifically because of these two calls:

```
let mut prediction = self.evaluate(input_data); // This mutates self

batch_loss += (self.loss)(target_data, &prediction);

self.backpropagation(target_data, input_data, &prediction); // This mutates self
```

I tried:

```
batches.par_bridge().into_par_iter().for_each(|(input_batch, target_batch)| {
        let mut batch_loss = 0_f32;

        for (input_data, target_data) in input_batch.iter().zip(target_batch.iter()) {
            let mut prediction = self.evaluate(input_data);

            batch_loss += (self.loss)(target_data, &prediction);

            self.backpropagation(target_data, input_data, &prediction);

        epoch_predictions.push(prediction);
    }
});
```

Even though I handle the thread racing for epoch_predictions I get

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable, as it is a captured variable in a `Fn` closure
  --> src/core/model.rs:79:46
   |
79 |                         let mut prediction = self.evaluate(input_data);
   |                                              ^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable

error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable, as it is a captured variable in a `Fn` closure
  --> src/core/model.rs:83:25
   |
83 |                         self.backpropagation(target_data, input_data, &prediction);
   |                         ^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

So, I know I have to refactor my code considerably, but I can't figure it out how.

How could I (in parallel) mutate the list of layers for a batch, registering the error and forward pass values of every batch sample without running into issues?

Comment: If you want to access `self` mutably you have to make sure it's only accessed by one thread at a time by wrapping `self` in a `Mutex`. Though given that almost all of the code in the parallel `for_each` requires that `Mutex` to be locked, your problem doesn't seem to benefit that mutch (or at all) from paralellization.